# How to go to checkout review section and throw an error in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

In my `checkout_type_onepage_save_order` observer, i have a code to do some validation and it will make the customer go to the checkout review and throw some error, in Magento 1.9 i can do it like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout()->setGotoSection('review');
throw new Mage_Core_Exception($helper->__('There was an error processing your order. Please read error message or contact us ajk.com'));
```

How can i do something similar like this in Magento 2.3.4?